# Write filename, servername/IP and date+time in spool file

Tags: oracle, logs, sqlplus

I'm having some problems to verify the installation/execution of some oracle scripts in different production servers. I've created a launcher script which executes all the sql scripts in sqlplus and writes the output in different spool files. But i wish to if i can define 'a header' to write before the sql output with sql filename, servername or server ip and date+time to ensure or have proofs to demonstrate the execution of these scripts.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the script written in? Is it executing on the database box or a remote one? Details!

Comment: You have also not updated the previous question you asked

Answer (score 2):

I hope my answer is not erroneous, because maybe I do not understand very well you question.

A simple solution can be the following.
In every server you can create an header file (**header.sql**) like this, for example:

```
SET PAGESIZE 0 LINESIZE 80 FEEDBACK OFF
SET TERMOUT OFF
SET APPINFO ON

SELECT 'The database is: ' || upper(instance_name) || '. The server is: ' || upper(host_name) || '.'
FROM v$instance;

SELECT 'Execution Time: ' || to_char(sysdate, 'HH24:MI MM/DD/YYYY') FROM dual;
```

For IP address, you can parse output of `host` command, maybe like this:

```
!host host_name
```

In the bash script file (**test.sh**) you can put the main calls...

```
sqlplus -s system/sys@TESTDB1 @modify.sql
sqlplus -s system/sys@TESTDB2 @insert.sql
sqlplus -s system/sys@MYDB @delete.sql
```

For example, a very basic sql script file can be like this one:

```
spool scripts.log APPEND
@header.sql
SELECT 'Filename: ' || sys_context('USERENV', 'MODULE') FROM dual;

-- beginning of the code.

    UPDATE test.A SET id = 11; -- sample code
    -- ..

-- end of the code.

PROMPT --------------------
SPOOL OFF
SET TERMOUT ON
EXIT
```

You need to put sql files in a folder assigned to the variable `SQLPATH`.

The log file appears like this one:

```
The database is: TESTDB1. The server is: SERVERA.
Execution Time: 18:39 12/28/2013
Filename: 01@ modify.sql
------------------- spool off
The database is: TESTDB2. The server is: SERVERA.
Execution Time: 18:39 12/28/2013
Filename: 01@ insert.sql
insert into C values(10)
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


------------------- spool off
The database is: MYDB. The server is: SERVERB.
Execution Time: 18:39 12/28/2013
Filename: 01@ delete.sql
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
col dt1 noprint new_value dt1

SELECT   TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'yyyymmdd') || '.log' dt1 FROM DUAL;

spool C:\log_file_&dt1
```

> *sql commands*

```
spool off
```

Comment: Hi will and thanks for the answer, but could you add a bit of explanation for those who don't speak PLSQL natively? This answer looks spammish to some of our readers because they don't understand what you're encouraging Jorge to do!